# How to get Python import working with dlib (using cmake and osx)

Tags: python, cmake, dlib

Sorry if this is basic but I'm trying to install dlib to use with python as mentioned in (http://blog.dlib.net/2014/04/dlib-187-released-make-your-own-object.html) "Make your own object detector in Python!".

I downloaded the install files, unzipped, and used cmake as in the install instructions (http://dlib.net/compile.html)

```
cd examples
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
cmake --build . --config Release
```

which seemed to work fine

However typing "import dlib" in Python just gives ImportError: No module named dlib.

Any idea how I tell Python how to find / use the thing?

Answer (score 8):

Just a note for reference that the easiest way to install is now to use:

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

Comment: since version 19 this should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 5):

Instead of manual file editing, you can pass `-DPYTHON_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=/path/to/your/libpython2.7.dylib` to `cmake`.

What `./compile_dlib_python_module.bat` does is

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ../../tools/python
```

So, just run the commands by one by one and instead of

```
cmake ../../tools/python
```

run

```
cmake ../../tools/python -DPYTHON_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/libpython2.7.dylib
```

Answer (score 5):

Dlib installation instructions for OSX (python3)

```
brew uninstall boost-python
brew uninstall boost
brew install boost-python --with-python3 --without-python
```

Installing default dlib

```
pip3 install dlib
```

**Following Gives Some speedup**
Installing dlib with AVX, SSE2, SSE4 instructions enabled (download the source code from dlib.net and execute from within the directory).

```
python setup.py install --yes USE_AVX_INSTRUCTIONS --yes USE_SSE2_INSTRUCTIONS --yes USE_SSE4_INSTRUCTIONS
```

Answer (score 4):

On ubuntu I had to do the following:

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-python-dev cmake
```

cd to `dlib-18.15/python_examples`

Then:

```
./compile_dlib_python_module.bat
```

I then copied the `dlib.so` to dist-packages so it would be in my path.

```
sudo cp dlib.so /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/
```

According to the documentation `compile_dlib_python_module.bat` will work on any os once you have both `CMake` and `boost-python` installed.

Comment: Thanks - I did the Mac equivalent and it worked except Python import dlib now segfaults. Onward...

Comment: Had a quick google and it seems it is related to boost-python, can you add the full traceback to pastebin?

Comment: Here's the traceback http://pastebin.com/wwcMVXML  the brew boost file was boost-1.56.0.mavericks.bottle.1.tar.gz and I'm on osx 10.9.5. Thanks in advance if you can figure anything

Comment: can you import from the system python?

Comment: I just tried the system python and it also segfaulted with a slightly different error http://pastebin.com/t74tD28e . I'm guessing it may be something to do with OSX Mavericks not being compatible with something perhaps

Comment: @Tim333 Did you figure anything out related to this? I just tried compiling on OSX and I'm getting the same seg-fault error.

Comment: @AdrianRosebrock, how did you install boost-python?

Comment: @PadraicCunninghamI installed via homebrew. I detailed my exact process here: http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/04/27/installing-boost-and-boost-python-on-osx-with-homebrew/

Comment: @AdrianRosebrock not yet

Comment: @AdrianRosebrock.  what python was boost-python built with?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham boost-python was built with brew version of Python, as far as I can tell. Although I do "brew info boost-python" I am seeing that it looks like it was compiled with Python3 support but not Python support which is odd:

==> Options
--c++11
 Build using C++11 mode
--universal
 Build a universal binary
--with-python3
 Build with python3 support
--without-python
 Build without python support
--HEAD
 Install HEAD version

Comment: Never mind that last comment, I misunderstood the options switches. This is the formula boost-python was built with: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/boost-python.rb

Comment: I was able to get it to work! Please see my answer to the question for the details.

Answer (score 4):

I finally got it to work! I'll be posting a detailed blog post about this later, but here's the gist for now. Basically, when I manually inspected the output of cmake, dlib was compiling and linking against the system version of Python *not* the Homebrew version of python.

If you're interested in the details, it appears that cmake was trying to compile and link against `/usr/lib/libpython2.7.dylib`. However, that is the system version of Python. It should be compiling a linking against `/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/libpython2.7.dylib` which is the Homebrew version of Python.

I manually edited `CMakeFiles/dlib_.dir/build.make` and `/CMakeFiles/dlib_.dir/link.txt` to point to the Homebrew dylib file instead of the system one. I was able to compile dlib and then run it without a segfault. And furthermore, I was able to run the object detectors without a problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are compiling the C++ example programs.  The python examples are in the python_examples folder.  Also, each example has instructions at the top that tell you how to use it.

Comment: Thanks. I subsequently found the python_examples instructions, brew installed boost-python, ran compile_dlib_python_module.bat, started Python and typed import dlib and Python segfaulted ("Segmentation fault: 11"  Identifier:      Python
Version:         2.7.8 (2.7.8)
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  bash [8652]
Responsible:     Terminal [184]
Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread) Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you use Conda, it's much easier.

```
conda install -c menpo dlib
```

https://anaconda.org/menpo/dlib

Answer (score 0):

for Python 3 support use:

```
python setup.py install --yes DPYTHON3
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already compiled [dlib](https://github.com/davisking/dlib) source code from github by cmake command.
Then you want to run python program to call dlib api.

You should compile dlib Python API as below,

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

Or

```
sudo python setup.py install --yes USE_AVX_INSTRUCTIONS
```

if you have a CPU that supports AVX instructions, since this makes some things run faster. Note that you need to have boost-python installed to compile the Python API.(Linked from [dlib](https://github.com/davisking/dlib) README.md)

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I encounted the same error with you.

When I looked at the folder `"C:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages"`, I found `"dlib-19.8.0-py3.4-win-amd64.egg\"`, it means I have compiled dlib successfully, but there is no `"dlib\"` folder under the `"C:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages"`, it is inside `"dlib-19.8.0-py3.4-win-amd64.egg\"` folder, so the solution is simple: just copy the `"dlib\"` folder to path `"C:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages"`, the Python interpreter will find the module and import it successfully.

Hope it will help!

[image]